# Getting a two-column dashboard in CiviCRM 5.33+

Tags: dashboard, dashlet

After the recent rewrite of the CiviCRM dashboard, many of the sites I work with have only a single column where previously they had two columns.  How does one restore the two-column behavior?

Answer (score 3):

It autoadjusts to screensize. I suppose you could overwrite the specified widths for css:

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/19235/files

Comment: I have a dev site and a live site that I'm viewing in the same browser (on a 40" screen) and one is displaying as a single column.  I'll look at that PR to see the CSS in question to troubleshoot.

Comment: Ah - I found the issue.  I've incompletely converted this site from Roundearth to civicrm-asset-plugin, and it's pulling the wrong CSS file.  Thank you.

Comment: Aha. Composer strikes again.