# Make CiviCRM dashboard full-width

Tags: dashboard, css, dashlet

This used to be achieved with the code linked but since the dashboard code was heavily revised in Civi 5.33+? the old code doesn't work. Ref: https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php%3Ftopic=24355.0.html

My admittedly hacky solution is to add this CSS, which does work cosmetically but if a user doesn't already have a dashlet in your dashboard, they won't be able to add one.

```
.crm-container .crm-flex-box {display: inherit;}
```

How can I make this work better?

I don't particularly find the 2 columns useful to viewing many dashlets, but this would be a good feature improvement that could be a setting per site? Maybe per user?

Related: [Getting a two-column dashboard in CiviCRM 5.33+](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/38718/getting-a-two-column-dashboard-in-civicrm-5-33)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, use the custom CSS option.

At `Administer > System Settings > Resource URLs > Custom CSS URL` enter eg `[civicrm.files]/css/tweaks.css`

Create `tweaks.css` with content:

```
/* Make dashboard a single column */
#civicrm-dashboard > .crm-flex-box > .crm-flex-2 {
  min-width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Nice and simple. In this case I'm only loading my custom CSS file on the front-end of the site courtesy of WP Admin Utilities so I'm using this simple extension to add styling to the dashboard: https://github.com/andyburnsco/smartbe.

Comment: Credit to Coleman for a version of this when I asked the same question previously!

Answer (score 2):

Edit: this solution was to support the 2-columns for those who still wanted it. To force 1-column, Aidan's answer is much simpler indeed.

You probably don't want to install this extension, because it also does questionable tweaks to contributions forms, but there is a JavaScript snippet that you might find useful:

https://github.com/coopsymbiotic/coop.symbiotic.symbioticux/blob/master/js/dashboard.js

It's loaded from the main php file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_civicrm_dashboard().
 */
function symbioticux_civicrm_dashboard($contactID, &$contentPlacement) {
  Civi::resources()
    ->addStyleFile('coop.symbiotic.symbioticux', 'css/dashboard.css')
    ->addScriptFile('coop.symbiotic.symbioticux', 'js/dashboard.js');
}
```

Although I'm pretty sure the CSS is not required. It's to hide things like the repeating pager in report dashlets, and other small tweaks.

This dashboard bug has been a long time annoyance for me - the dashboard rarely looks good with two columns - but I'm not sure what a good fix might be.